# MacBook screen does not work when using OS X but works with Boot Camp

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, screen

A while ago I had some liquid spilled on my 2009 MacBook. After that accident the internal screen is not working under OS X but works perfectly fine when using Windows under Boot Camp on the same MacBook. When an external monitor is connected it also works, even under OS X.

Obviously this is a very puzzling issue since the screen works fine only under Boot Camp. 
I recently upgraded to Mavericks hoping that that might help with fixing the problem but unfortunately nothing has changed under the new OS X.

Has anyone come across an issue like that before and can offer any advice?

Comment: Do you have two graphics adaptors? Seems that one of those died.

Comment: @MaxRied, No I don't think there are two graphics adaptors. That's the MacBook in question: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.0-white-13-early-2009-nvidia-specs.html And it seems that there is only one graphics processor there...

Comment: did you find out the problem? I also had the same problem because of water spill